# How to get average stock price from an array?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, average, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to get average stock prices from a dynamic list.

In my example, I've made a bought stocks in a few different days. And I've sold some of them (not all). So, I have some stocks available that I want to find out the average price:

```
 +------------+---------+------------+---+----------+-------------+
 | date       | buy qty |  buy price |   | sell qty | sell price  |
 +------------+---------+------------+---+----------+-------------+
 | 08/30/2019 |  259    |    $86.02  |   |    0     |     $0.00   |
 | 08/29/2019 |  22     |    $85.77  |   |    0     |     $0.00   |
 | 08/28/2019 |  18     |    $84.22  |   |    0     |     $0.00   |
 | 08/27/2019 |  30     |    $84.00  |   |    0     |     $0.00   |
 | 08/26/2019 |  44     |    $85.76  |   |    6     |    $86.29   |
 | 08/25/2019 |  14     |    $85.77  |   |   14     |    $86.21   |
 +------------+---------+------------+---+----------+-------------+
```

`Available stocks: 367`

How to get an average price from stocks not sold, from the earlier to the latest date?

Manually, the result must be: $85.72

I've built an [example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RUpK5Fj6pdKnsAwqNagFXLPAdbPsWEamsl9aKlONK7Y/edit#gid=0).

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome. Would you explain - what, exactly, is your problem? Your spreadsheet already shows the correct formula in cell H25 (`=AVERAGE.WEIGHTED(H19:H23,G19:G23)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(AVERAGE.WEIGHTED(
 QUERY(IF(C4:C12-G4:G12<>0, D4:D12,        ), "where Col1 is not null", 0),
 QUERY(IF(C4:C12-G4:G12<>0, C4:C12-G4:G12, ), "where Col1 is not null", 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot!
Would you mind help me out with a second hardest situation? You can see it at the same URL in "Example 2" sheet...